# How interpreter of Python recognize undefined global variable in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How interpreter of Python recognize undefined global variable (`a`) in function in the following code ?

```
def show():
    print(a)

a = 1
show()
```

Python is interactive language, so it processes each line of code line by line.

Given this, it should throw an error at the line with undefined variable (`print(a)`).
However, it works without error.

How does interpreter of Python recognize the undefined variable (`a`) ?
Or is it just recognized as letters until `show function` is called?

I converted the above code to bytecode, but I didn't understand well it...

Comment: The value that will be used in the function is the one the variable has when the function is executed. So it would make no sense to see if it exists when the function gets defined anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your function inside a python interpreter, python treats it as a sort of black box. It initializes the variables that are **not defined inside and outside the function** as *free variables*. Then, it stores a reference to the function inside the global table (you can access it using `globals()`). This global table holds the values for global variables and global function references.
When you define the variable `a` python stores it inside the global dictionary as well. Just like the function before it.
After that when you call your function, python sees a variable `a`. It knows that the variable is *free*, therefore, must be declared inside the global variable by now. Then it looks up the global table and uses the value that is stored.

Comment: Python doesn't look in the local variable table for `a`. Because `a` isn't assigned anywhere in the function, Python knows it's a global variable and that's where it will look.

Comment: Doesn't it understand that there is no definition for `a` by looking inside the local table?

Comment: It's not a global variable; it's a *free* variable whose value is looked up in the closest containing scope where the variable is defined. (That scope will be the global scope when the function is defined in the global scope.)

Comment: It doesn't look in the local table, you can run `dis.dis(show)` and see only a `LOAD_GLOBAL` instruction. There would be no point in looking in `locals()` as directly modifying `locals()` is not supported and `a` isn't assigned.

Comment: The code generator determines if `a` is local or not. Code to access the correct scope is generated when the function is defined, not based on a failed lookup at runtime.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the info. I edited the answer, feel free to comment even more.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful responses! What format is the free variable `a` which is name before name binding stored inside the global table?

Comment: @DH The type of all variables inside python is determined at runtime. So when you put a string inside `a`, when the code is running, python dynamically concludes that this variable is a type string.

Answer (score 0):

Python is run line by line, and in saying that, it will skip over the function until the function is called. So even though it's line by line, it's still running afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

**Use of global keyword:**

To access a global variable inside a function, there is no need to use global keyword. As `a` is not assigned inside the function, python will look at the global scope.
We use global keyword to assign a new value to the global variable.

This example throws an error -

```
def show():
    a = a + 5
    print(a)

a = 1
show()
```

Error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment